# C# Get all items from a database row

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I want to create an edit window to edit an Row in the Database.

How I can read all items from a database row?

My code until now is:

```
private void FirmCustomerValues()
    {
        config conf = new config();
        connection = new MySqlConnection(conf.connection_string);
        try
        {
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM firmenkunden WHERE id='" + firmCustomerID + "'",connection);

                MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    foreach (var row in reader)
                    {
                        System.Windows.Controls.TextBox textbox = new TextBox();

                        // Textbox Properties
                        textbox.Width = 159;
                        textbox.Name = "";
                        textbox.Text = reader[1].ToString();

                        textboxWP.Children.Add(textbox);
                    }



                }

            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

But this is not working.
Has anyone a idea how to solve this?

I think i need a for loop too. Im new to C# so sorry if the answer is simple.

Comment: How is textBoxWP set up?

Comment: I could be wrong but i think you dont need that foreach inside while, you read one row at a time anyways. It should still work with it tho.
Im not that great at programming myself so i'd say run it in debug mode and see if you get a row returned from your database. If you do, go further line per line and see where it doesnt work :)

Comment: Shouldn't this reader[1].ToString(); be row.ToString(); ?

Comment: You might consider using the third-party library "Dapper". It's much easier to program, safer against SQL Injections and faster, too.

Comment: textboxWP is my WrapPanel. I have 2 Wrappanels 1 for Labels which reads the columns from database and 1 for textboxes which have to read the value from the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the foreach loop.

`reader.Read()` itterates through the rows returned.

You can use `reader.HasRows()` to determine if there are any rows

Also try to use `textbox.Text = reader["ColumnName"].ToString();`
as this is easier to read.

To generate a unique textbox name

```
var textBoxCounter =0;
```

Inside your Read() loop

```
textbox.Name = string.Format("txtText{0}", textBoxCounter);
textbox.Text = reader[1].ToString();
textBoxCounter += 1;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: How to use reader.HasRows() ?
I made:  `while (reader.Read())
                    {
                       
                            System.Windows.Controls.TextBox textbox = new TextBox();

                            // Textbox Properties
                            textbox.Width = 159;
                            textbox.Name = "";
                            textbox.Text = reader["ColumnName"].ToString();

                            textboxWP.Children.Add(textbox);
                    }`
 
but he can't do `textbox.Text = reader["ColumnName"].ToString();`

Comment: And It just create one TextBox instead of a textbox for each value in that row.

Comment: You need to give them unique names. You're setting them to blank. what is textboxWP?  I've edited the answer

Comment: I've fixed the problem. textbox WP is the WrapPanel name.